# HtmlUnit Button without a ID,Name or Value [Xpath not working]

Tags: java, html, button, xpath, htmlunit

I know there are some answers around this question in the forum.
But none of them seems to work for my problem. I want to click on a Button:

Here is the side-Code (pretty easy side to test a login):

```
<head/>
 <body>
   <form action="/login_check" method="post" class="login-form">

          <label for="username">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" 
                 class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" name="_username" 
                 value="" required style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/>

          <label for="password">Passwort</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" 
                 class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" name="_password"
                 required /><br>

         <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-form-submit"
                type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>">
            Anmelden
         </button>

   </form>
 </body>
```

Chrome F12 "Copy Xpath"

```
getFirstByXPath("/html/body/form/button");
```

Any ideas how to click the button? Thanks

Here is short snap of my Code:

```
String pageText1 = page1.asText();
System.out.println(pageText1);

HtmlButton htmlElement = page1.getFirstByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Anmelden')]");
htmlElement.click();

HtmlButton htmlElement1 = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body/form/button");
htmlElement1.click();

Thread.sleep(2000);
String pageText2 = page1.asText();
System.out.println(pageText2);
```

page1.asText1() ist the same as page1.asText2

> E-MailTest@test.dePasswort123  Anmelden
>
> E-MailTest@test.dePasswort123  Anmelden

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: cant you give it a id?

Comment: You need to ensure first that `page.asXml()`contains that button, otherwise please post your complete case

Comment: i´m sorry .. totally forgot to tell you guys what i´m trying to do: i just wanna click the button 

@AhmedAshour page.asXml() contains the button <button class ..

Comment: Existing answers would help you, otherwise post your complete case, so others can reproduce and investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply match required `button` by text content:

```
//button[.="Anmelden"]
```

or by `type` attribute value:

```
//button[@type="submit"]
```

If it's not working you might add more details to your ticket about why *Xpath not working* as it's not completely clear

Comment: sorry for this first post. Now you have some more information. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath for your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Anmelden')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey RNS, added "HtmlUnitDriver" to my program and tried your idea. But i´m getting a error : 

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //*[contains(text(),'Anmelden')]

Comment: or something like this:

The xpath expression '//*[contains(button[@type='submit')]' cannot be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//form[@action='/login_check']//button[@type='submit']
```